# Create Office 2013 apps in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, office-2013

I am trying to create an office 2013 app in visual studio 2013, however I the only options I can choose for my project in tab "Office" are : Office 2010 workbook / template / add-in .

I've heard that for some people it works even if the office version installed is 2013.

But in my case it doesn't work - when I am trying to run office 2010 add-in/template project I am getting an error, which states that proper version of the application is not installed on this computer.

( I have installed version 2013, which I want to develop for and project is for version 2010)

I know that **SOMEWHERE**, but I don't know where, there are office 2013 templates for visual studio..

Maybe those could help.

Any help would be appreciated.

My goal now is just to create HelloWorld office 2013 project in visual studio.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure there exists. We are already developing for it :)

Here is where you find the [Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2012)

Comment: Ya I've already found it, but thanks - that's the correct solution to get office 2013 template / workbook / add-in. However in official office 2013 tutorial about creating apps found here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp142161(v=office.15)
it is written that I should create a new project in following way:
New->Project->Visual C#-> expand office/sharepoint 2013 and here choose **Apps**, but there is nothing like **Apps** here, there are only : Office 2013 template / workbook / add-in. I don't know if those are ok too?

Comment: The appear when you install the Toolkit. Independently if it's a TaskPane app, a mail app or a SharePoint app; you definitively should try to use the toolkit. It's a preview, but also office so, that should be the way.

Comment: Where can I find that Toolkit?

Comment: The address I reference is the installer.

Comment: I insatlled the toolkit and still don't see any options for creating an outlook add-in project.

Answer (score 3):

You can also obtain the Office Dev Tools via the Web Platform Installer.

More information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2012/08/17/10340229.aspx).