# Developing Office 2013 App in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, office-2013

I have an Office Project (currently developed in Visual Studio 2010) which works for all versions of Office up to (but not including) 2013.

I want to be able to build a version of the app to work in 2013 but I can't seem to discover the equivalent of this [Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=261869) (found from this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544611/create-office-2013-apps-in-visual-studio)) but for VS 2010. I have spent a few hours looking on Google and to be quite honest I'm not convinced what I'm trying to do is even possible!

All help would be very much appreciated.

Louis

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean an app for office?  (using the new JavaScript APIs)?  If so that type of project can only be created in VS 2012 and above. If you are referring to an add-in you will likely also need a newer version of VS to target 2013.